# SupportMapFragment nested in another fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, supportmapfragment

i'm implementing and Android app where i'm trying to use a SupportMapFragment inside another fragment.
The map fragment works fine, i can see the map and i get no errors.
But, in the main activity, i'm trying to get the GoogleMap object from the nested fragment, but all i get is null. Any idea how could i overcome this?

**main_activity.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

**fragment layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#E8E8E8">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="117dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />
<LinearLayout/>
```

in MainActivity.java::onCreate()

```
// Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        //fm is null here
```

Comment: does your activity class extend `FragmentActivity`?

Comment: @Raghunandan yes, .... extends FragmentActivity implements
  ActionBar.TabListener {

Comment: can you post the stacktrace.

Comment: @Raghunandan I do not get any errors. My problem is that the fm object is null. The map works fine, is loaded wihtout errors

Comment: @maephisto, what was the final solution that you used to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear that you actually *have* "nested fragments" here. I only see one fragment: `SupportMapFragment`.

If your `ViewPager` is inside a fragment, and your `FragmentPagerAdapter` is using the `SupportMapFragment`, then you need to be calling `findFragmentById()` on the *child* `FragmentManager`, the one that `FragmentPagerAdapter` is using.

If your `ViewPager` is not inside a fragment, then I do not believe that you have nested fragments. However, your `ViewPager` probably has not instantiated any pages yet in `onCreate()` of your overall activity, and so your fragment does not yet exist. Wait until your `FragmentPagerAdapter` has created your `SupportMapFragment`, *then* try to use it.